# Very slow insert of multiple messages to Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

For testing purpose I want to generate about one million messages to MQ. But after 200-300 messages inserting becomes very slow, near 30 seconds for 100 messages. And after 3700 messages I have got MQException (Reason 2010).

My code in groovy

```
import com.ibm.mq.*

MQEnvironment.@hostname = "srv-cci2"
MQEnvironment.@port = 1414
MQEnvironment.@channel = "SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN"
MQEnvironment.disableTracing();
MQException.log = null;

def queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM_srv_cci2")

int putOpenOpts = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

def putMsg = new MQMessage();
putMsg.setVersion(MQC.MQMD_VERSION_2);
putMsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
putMsg.characterSet = 1250;


def xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>

"""

for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
    def putQ = queueManager.accessQueue("SOA_EVENT.IN", putOpenOpts);
    putMsg.writeString(xml);
    def pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
    putQ.put(putMsg, pmo);
    putQ.close()

    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        println ("" + new Date() + " " + i)
    }
}

queueManager.disconnect()
```

So main question - do this possible - quickly insert 1 million messages to Webspere MQ? And how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2010 reason code is defined in the following constant name:  MQRC_DATA_LENGTH_ERROR

In each itereation you call:

```
putMsg.writeString(xml);
```

But it is never reset. Looks to me that you keep adding more content to the message and posting it (each message is larger than the previous one).

Comment: Also is there a need to call accessQueue and close it in each itereration instead of calling it once outside the loop?

Comment: Correct on both counts, Eddy.  The message keeps getting larger and there is no need to open and close the queue for each PUT.  In addition, reuse of the same message object means that the MQMD output fields are potentially fed back in on the second and subsequent PUT calls.  Generally, either a new message object would be generated for each PUT or if the same message will be reused, initialize it in one object and then copy over a second object each time which will be used for the PUT.  That way the MQMD has default settings on each PUT.  Same thing with the PMO object.